# classList.remove is not working as it should?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with this conditional, the goal is to show the `li` with `desc` when focusing on it. When another is focused in the domem the previously focused one should be removed.

In other words: Once one `desc` is showing the the other must disappear, what is strange is that it works for 2 times ok, then it stops doing what it should be doing.
I suspect that it might have something to do with the listener, I have to use `foucusin` thought.

Maybe someone will be able to see where the issue could be:

```js
let parent = document.body
  parent.addEventListener('focusin', function (e) {
        let link = e.target
        if (document.querySelector('.selected')) {
        let suspect = document.querySelector('.selected');
        suspect.classList.remove('.selected');
        suspect.style.display = 'none';
        }
        let checker = link.parentElement.querySelector('.desc');
        checker.classList.add('selected');
        checker.style.display = 'flex';
  })
```

```css
ul {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul> 
  <li class='item' contenteditable=true>1<li>
  <li class='desc' style="display: none;">B<li>
</ul>

<ul> 
  <li class='item' contenteditable=true>2<li>
  <li class='desc' style="display: none;">B<li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Would it be `remove('selected');`? As the classes in classList don't have a `.` at the beginning?

Comment: The function expects a class name, not a CSS class selector. Related, but not the same thing.

Comment: @evolutionxbox working..... that was soo amature :(

Comment: @evolutionxbox why was it ,half working btw ? the class was getting deleted, until a certain point any clue ?

Comment: The class is never being removed?

Comment: @evolutionxbox true.. thanks only the display went to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply removed the `.` before `selected`, this was making the `querySelector` look for the wrong value ( `.selected` instead of simply `selected` ).

The fixed snippet can be tested below, hopefully that helps you:

```js
let parent = document.body
  parent.addEventListener('focusin', function (e) {
        let link = e.target
        if (document.querySelector('.selected')) {
        let suspect = document.querySelector('.selected');
        suspect.classList.remove('selected');
        suspect.style.display = 'none';
        }
        let checker = link.parentElement.querySelector('.desc');
        checker.classList.add('selected');
        checker.style.display = 'flex';
  })
```

```css
ul {
width: 40px;
background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul> 
<li class='item' contenteditable=true>1<li>
<li class='desc' style="display: none;">B<li>
</ul>

<ul> 
<li class='item' contenteditable=true>2<li>
<li class='desc' style="display: none;">B<li>
<ul>
```